# break line in jsp page by using a string on session

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I have `doPost` in a servlet  -

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.getSession().setAttribute("sysMsg","now we gonna to break line \n");

        // forward to printLine.jsp page 
            dispather.forward(request, response) ; 
    }
```

And jsp page (says , `printLine.jsp`)  -

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <font size="30" color="Red">${sysMsg} </font>
</body>
</html>
```

I want that in `printLine.jsp` the printing of `sysMsg` finally break line ... For that in put `\n` in the end of `sysMsg` when set him in the servlet  , but this way didn't work .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `<br/>` instead

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("sysMsg","now we gonna to break line <br/>");
```